# query to find the previous and next rows from the current one which includes order by clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I execute the following query:

```
SELECT quotesid 
FROM quotestable 
WHERE quotesauthor LIKE '%Mahatma%'  
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

Which gives me the following results: (`quotesid` - is the primary-key)

```
 968
 158
 159
 160
 161
```

### my requirement:

I need the next and previous `quotesid` (`ORDER BY popularity DESC`). for example if I am in 158th record. the next and previous values should be 159 and 968 respectively which I need this in a single query.

### my query

```
SELECT *  
FROM quotestable 
WHERE 
    (quotesid = (SELECT MIN(quotesid) FROM quotestable where quotesid > 158 and quotesauthor like '%Mah%' ) 
 OR quotesid = (SELECT MAX(quotesid) FROM quotestable where quotesid < 158 and quotesauthor like '%Mah%' ))
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

This does not work. This gives me only one record - 159.
is there a way to write a single query and get the results as desired?

fiddle:

[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d899/5)

Comment: post the output what you want @venkat

Comment: select * from table where (quesid >= 158 ) or (quesid <= 158) and popularity like '%mah%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this will work for you. It gives your query `row number` index and then `left outer join` itself shifted by `+1` and `-1` record to produce `[next]` and `[previous]` columns.

```
with cte as
(
    select quotesid, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by popularity desc) as [RowNo]
    from quotestable
)
select cte.quotesid, [next].quotesid as [Next], [prev].quotesid as [Previous]
from cte left outer join cte as [next] on cte.RowNo = ([next].RowNo - 1)
         left outer join cte as [prev] on cte.RowNo = ([prev].RowNo + 1)
```

Result:

```
quotesid Next   Previous
------------------------
968      158    NULL
158      159    968
159      160    158
160      161    159
161      NULL   160
```

sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ac0b/4

Comment: order by primary key works perfectly. the issue is I need a order by different key. I would suggest you to add one more column called popularity and order by that clause.

Comment: this doesnot work. It would have worked because you have the popularity as 1,2,3,4,5,. Please shuffle the values (like 100,200,90,101,5)  and try.

Comment: @Venkat ok updated sql fiddle and answer. The query is ordered by `popularity desc` a in principle works.

Comment: Looks like it works well when the popularity is not NULL. if the value is null it doesnot work properly.

Comment: @Venkat I checked your link but can see only single select and no data. I also tried `null` values (see this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ac0b/7) and seems to work good

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY popularity DESC) rn
    FROM quotestable
    WHERE quotesauthor LIKE '%Mah%')
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE 1 = ABS(t.rn - (SELECT rn FROM t WHERE quotesid = 158))
```

You can use this to have your previous and next in one row:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY popularity DESC) rn
    FROM quotestable
    WHERE quotesauthor LIKE '%Mah%')
SELECT t1.quotesid, t2.quotesid PrevID, t3.quotesid NextID
FROM t t1 
    LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn - 1
    LEFT JOIN t t3 ON t1.rn = t3.rn + 1
WHERE t1.rn = (SELECT rn FROM t WHERE quotesid = 158)
```

Comment: This doesnot work. Let me put in a sqlfiddle and open this query to every one over here.

Answer (score 0):

```
select quotestable.quotesid, b.quotesid nextQuoteID, c.quotesid previousQuoteID from quotestable
join (
    select a.quotesID, max(b.popularity) previousQuoteID, min(c.popularity) nextQuoteID
    from quotestable a
    left join quotestable b
    on a.popularity > b.popularity
    left join quotestable c
    on a.popularity < c.popularity
    where a.author like '%Mahatma%'
    group by a.quotesid
) x
on quotestable.quotesid = x.quotesid
left join quotestable b
on b.popularity = x.previousquoteid
left join quotestable c
on c.popularity = x.nextquoteid
order by quotestable.popularity desc
```